# X.1, X.2, X.3 appearing when merging two data frames in R

Tags: r

I am merging two dfs ("Tokens.Single" and "Tokens.Mixed") in R with the following code:

```
data <- full_join(Tokens.Single, Tokens.Mixed)
```

Here are the dfs using the dput function to give more indication of what my dfs look like:

```
> dput(Tokens.Single)
structure(list(Filename = structure(c(6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 30L, 31L, 
32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 38L, 39L, 
40L, 41L), .Label = c("t4_block1_heed1.mp3", "t4_block1_heed2.mp3", 
"t4_block1_heed3.mp3", "t4_block1_heed4.mp3", "t4_block1_heed5.mp3", 
"t4_block1_hoed1.mp3", "t4_block1_hoed2.mp3", "t4_block1_hoed3.mp3", 
"t4_block1_hoed4.mp3", "t4_block1_hoed5.mp3", "t4_block1_whod1.mp3", 
"t4_block1_whod2.mp3", "t4_block1_whod3.mp3", "t4_block1_whod4.mp3", 
"t4_block1_whod5.mp3", "t4_block2_heed1.mp3", "t4_block2_heed2.mp3", 
"t4_block2_heed4.mp3", "t4_block2_heed5.mp3", "t4_block2_hoed1.mp3", 
"t4_block2_hoed3.mp3", "t4_block2_hoed4.mp3", "t4_block2_hoed5.mp3", 
"t4_block2_whod2.mp3", "t4_block2_whod4.mp3", "t4_block2_whod5.mp3", 
"t4_block3_heed1.mp3", "t4_block3_heed4.mp3", "t4_block3_heed5.mp3", 
"t4_block3_hoed1.mp3", "t4_block3_hoed2.mp3", "t4_block3_hoed4.mp3", 
"t4_block3_hoed5.mp3", "t4_block3_whod1.mp3", "t4_block3_whod2.mp3", 
"t4_block3_whod3.mp3", "t4_block3_whod5.mp3", "t4_block4_heed2.mp3", 
"t4_block4_heed3.mp3", "t4_block4_heed4.mp3", "t4_block4_heed5.mp3", 
"t4_block4_hoed1.mp3", "t4_block4_hoed2.mp3", "t4_block4_hoed3.mp3", 
"t4_block4_whod1.mp3", "t4_block4_whod2.mp3", "t4_block4_whod3.mp3", 
"t4_block4_whod5.mp3"), class = "factor"), Talker = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "T4", class = "factor"), 
    Duration = c(497L, 517L, 580L, 563L, 569L, 486L, 506L, 536L, 
    545L, 554L, 516L, 600L, 607L, 577L, 537L, 583L, 544L, 566L, 
    567L, 616L, 652L, 564L, 517L, 612L, 564L, 632L, 662L, 565L, 
    594L, 622L, 552L, 542L, 539L, 554L, 600L, 607L, 577L, 594L, 
    563L, 623L, 602L, 531L, 642L, 624L, 654L, 576L, 556L, 608L
    ), F0 = c(196L, 204L, 204L, 197L, 203L, 216L, 208L, 223L, 
    213L, 219L, 196L, 202L, 205L, 202L, 208L, 205L, 206L, 197L, 
    202L, 195L, 200L, 201L, 210L, 202L, 208L, 195L, 196L, 195L, 
    205L, 208L, 203L, 203L, 212L, 213L, 210L, 206L, 204L, 201L, 
    198L, 199L, 203L, 193L, 195L, 208L, 201L, 195L, 205L, 202L
    ), F1 = c(576L, 553L, 579L, 586L, 601L, 398L, 390L, 398L, 
    389L, 404L, 587L, 560L, 562L, 553L, 393L, 397L, 382L, 553L, 
    592L, 556L, 571L, 387L, 392L, 398L, 400L, 580L, 580L, 554L, 
    403L, 391L, 388L, 393L, 382L, 375L, 384L, 392L, 388L, 387L, 
    393L, 402L, 406L, 388L, 391L, 412L, 410L, 404L, 401L, 420L
    ), F2 = c(1339L, 1381L, 1381L, 1347L, 1394L, 1484L, 1521L, 
    1539L, 1430L, 1454L, 1353L, 1378L, 1325L, 1357L, 1424L, 1563L, 
    1578L, 1350L, 1397L, 1273L, 1319L, 1548L, 1452L, 1499L, 1515L, 
    1358L, 1347L, 1248L, 1575L, 1438L, 1414L, 1548L, 3001L, 2916L, 
    2948L, 2973L, 2947L, 2943L, 2913L, 2987L, 2940L, 3010L, 3008L, 
    2972L, 2963L, 2991L, 3007L, 2989L), F3 = c(2831L, 2779L, 
    2915L, 2875L, 2712L, 2730L, 2793L, 2779L, 2772L, 2692L, 2718L, 
    2856L, 2674L, 2659L, 2717L, 2584L, 2829L, 2726L, 2685L, 2866L, 
    2793L, 2614L, 2636L, 2907L, 2822L, 2932L, 2882L, 2882L, 2650L, 
    2929L, 2809L, 2737L, 3623L, 3607L, 3584L, 3576L, 3680L, 3641L, 
    3590L, 3556L, 3584L, 3640L, 3656L, 3686L, 3516L, 3552L, 3513L, 
    3579L), Word = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("heed", 
    "hoed", "whod"), class = "factor"), Vowel = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L), .Label = c("i", "o", "u"), class = "factor"), F1.Mean = c(564L, 
    564L, 564L, 564L, 564L, 394L, 394L, 394L, 394L, 394L, 564L, 
    564L, 564L, 564L, 394L, 394L, 394L, 564L, 564L, 564L, 564L, 
    394L, 394L, 394L, 394L, 564L, 564L, 564L, 394L, 394L, 394L, 
    394L, 398L, 398L, 398L, 398L, 398L, 398L, 398L, 398L, 398L, 
    398L, 398L, 398L, 398L, 398L, 398L, 398L), F2.Mean = c(1328L, 
    1328L, 1328L, 1328L, 1328L, 1496L, 1496L, 1496L, 1496L, 1496L, 
    1328L, 1328L, 1328L, 1328L, 1496L, 1496L, 1496L, 1328L, 1328L, 
    1328L, 1328L, 1496L, 1496L, 1496L, 1496L, 1328L, 1328L, 1328L, 
    1496L, 1496L, 1496L, 1496L, 2969L, 2969L, 2969L, 2969L, 2969L, 
    2969L, 2969L, 2969L, 2969L, 2969L, 2969L, 2969L, 2969L, 2969L, 
    2969L, 2969L), Distance = c(16L, 54L, 55L, 29L, 76L, 13L, 
    25L, 43L, 66L, 43L, 34L, 50L, 4L, 31L, 72L, 67L, 83L, 25L, 
    74L, 56L, 11L, 52L, 44L, 5L, 20L, 34L, 25L, 81L, 80L, 58L, 
    82L, 52L, 36L, 58L, 25L, 7L, 24L, 28L, 56L, 18L, 30L, 42L, 
    40L, 14L, 13L, 23L, 38L, 30L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-48L))
> dput(Tokens.Mixed)
structure(list(Filename = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 
32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 
45L, 46L, 47L), .Label = c("t1_block1_hoed3", "t1_block1_hoed5", 
"t1_block2_hoed3", "t1_block2_whod1", "t1_block2_whod5", "t1_block3_heed2", 
"t1_block3_heed3", "t1_block3_heed5", "t1_block3_hoed2", "t1_block3_whod3", 
"t1_block4_heed1", "t2_block1_heed3", "t2_block1_heed4", "t2_block1_hoed3", 
"t2_block1_whod1", "t2_block1_whod4", "t2_block2_hoed3", "t2_block2_hoed4", 
"t2_block2_hoed5", "t2_block3_whod1", "t2_block4_heed2", "t2_block4_heed5", 
"t2_block4_whod2", "t3_block1_heed1", "t3_block1_whod5", "t3_block2_heed5", 
"t3_block2_whod5", "t3_block3_hoed1", "t3_block3_hoed4", "t3_block3_whod4", 
"t3_block4_heed1", "t3_block4_heed3", "t3_block4_hoed3", "t3_block4_hoed4", 
"t3_block4_whod5", "t4_block1_heed5", "t4_block1_hoed1", "t4_block1_hoed2", 
"t4_block1_whod4", "t4_block2_hoed2", "t4_block2_whod5", "t4_block3_heed2", 
"t4_block3_heed3", "t4_block3_whod1", "t4_block3_whod3", "t4_block4_heed1", 
"t4_block4_hoed2"), class = "factor"), Talker = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("T1", 
"T2", "T3", "T4"), class = "factor"), Duration = c(468L, 532L, 
537L, 492L, 427L, 427L, 510L, 482L, 545L, 504L, 499L, 511L, 584L, 
641L, 510L, 582L, 590L, 523L, 572L, 609L, 641L, 558L, 488L, 519L, 
555L, 402L, 538L, 520L, 470L, 515L, 407L, 509L, 483L, 474L, 460L, 
432L, 577L, 497L, 517L, 545L, 574L, 544L, 597L, 627L, 564L, 612L, 
661L, 662L), F0 = c(232L, 239L, 221L, 256L, 233L, 233L, 230L, 
239L, 235L, 214L, 221L, 238L, 210L, 210L, 219L, 233L, 230L, 223L, 
239L, 223L, 238L, 219L, 224L, 243L, 203L, 208L, 200L, 217L, 199L, 
207L, 212L, 202L, 199L, 194L, 192L, 197L, 204L, 196L, 204L, 213L, 
202L, 206L, 203L, 194L, 201L, 202L, 196L, 196L), F1 = c(628L, 
670L, 640L, 489L, 461L, 461L, 448L, 360L, 324L, 619L, 417L, 383L, 
357L, 356L, 602L, 336L, 348L, 586L, 685L, 654L, 306L, 293L, 291L, 
288L, 422L, 415L, 420L, 414L, 571L, 581L, 428L, 409L, 420L, 569L, 
587L, 433L, 388L, 576L, 553L, 389L, 543L, 382L, 409L, 406L, 387L, 
398L, 403L, 580L), F2 = c(1076L, 1547L, 1304L, 1234L, 1511L, 
1511L, 2837L, 2559L, 2884L, 1205L, 1108L, 2500L, 2803L, 2839L, 
1293L, 968L, 1262L, 1315L, 1260L, 1186L, 1190L, 2780L, 2723L, 
1204L, 2779L, 1855L, 2718L, 1643L, 1348L, 1392L, 2176L, 2609L, 
2684L, 1486L, 1459L, 2118L, 2947L, 1339L, 1381L, 1430L, 1215L, 
1578L, 3099L, 3036L, 1548L, 1499L, 3058L, 1347L), F3 = c(2521L, 
2606L, 2735L, 2772L, 3550L, 3550L, 3226L, 3126L, 3315L, 2922L, 
2874L, 3114L, 3997L, 3877L, 2786L, 2695L, 2725L, 2848L, 2778L, 
2880L, 2891L, 3867L, 3722L, 2882L, 3464L, 3227L, 3269L, 2804L, 
2754L, 2861L, 2973L, 3351L, 3426L, 2900L, 2755L, 2980L, 3680L, 
2831L, 2779L, 2772L, 2930L, 2829L, 3627L, 3619L, 2614L, 2907L, 
3642L, 2882L), Word = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("heed", "hoed", 
"whod"), class = "factor"), Vowel = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("i", 
"o", "u"), class = "factor"), F1.Mean = c(639.25, 639.25, 639.25, 
457, 457, 457, 378.75, 378.75, 378.75, 639.25, 457, 378.75, 324.25, 
324.25, 631.75, 319.5, 319.5, 631.75, 631.75, 631.75, 319.5, 
324.25, 324.25, 319.5, 417.75, 422.5, 417.75, 422.5, 577, 577, 
422.5, 417.75, 417.75, 577, 577, 422.5, 401.5, 563, 563, 389, 
563, 389, 401.5, 401.5, 389, 389, 401.5, 563), F2.Mean = c(1283, 
1283, 1283, 1341, 1341, 1341, 2695, 2695, 2695, 1283, 1341, 2695, 
2786.25, 2786.25, 1263.5, 1156, 1156, 1263.5, 1263.5, 1263.5, 
1156, 2786.25, 2786.25, 1156, 2697.5, 1948, 2697.5, 1948, 1421.25, 
1421.25, 1948, 2697.5, 2697.5, 1421.25, 1421.25, 1948, 3035, 
1320.5, 1320.5, 1513.75, 1320.5, 1513.75, 3035, 3035, 1513.75, 
1513.75, 3035, 1320.5), Distance = c(207, 266, 21, 112, 170, 
170, 158, 137, 197, 81, 236, 195, 37, 62, 42, 189, 110, 69, 53, 
81, 37, 32, 71, 57, 82, 93, 21, 305, 73, 30, 228, 89, 14, 65, 
39, 170, 89, 23, 61, 84, 107, 65, 64, 5, 34, 17, 23, 31), F1.erb = c(25.450244282939, 
27.1523306840273, 25.9365546832499, 19.8171488126706, 18.6824245452785, 
18.6824245452785, 18.1555882782749, 14.5893120093281, 13.1303808083953, 
25.0855114827058, 16.899286410805, 15.5214069432574, 14.4677344092503, 
14.4272085425578, 24.396571748932, 13.6166912087062, 14.1030016090171, 
23.7481578818507, 27.7602186844159, 26.503916816946, 12.4009152079289, 
11.8740789409254, 11.7930272075402, 11.6714496074625, 17.1019157442679, 
16.8182346774199, 17.0208640108828, 16.7777088107273, 23.140269881462, 
23.5455285483878, 17.3450709444234, 16.5750794772644, 17.0208640108828, 
23.0592181480769, 23.7886837485433, 17.5477002778863, 15.7240362767203, 
23.3428992149249, 22.4108042809956, 15.7645621434128, 22.0055456140699, 
15.4808810765648, 16.5750794772644, 16.4535018771867, 15.6835104100277, 
16.129294943646, 16.3319242771089, 23.5050026816952), F2.erb = c(43.6058325612139, 
62.6935157734182, 52.8457301671217, 50.0089194986413, 61.2345845724854, 
61.2345845724854, 114.971883806844, 103.705692866307, 116.876599541395, 
48.8336693645565, 44.9026602953764, 101.314666731445, 113.594004339296, 
115.052935540229, 52.3999456335034, 39.2290389584155, 51.1436437660334, 
53.2915147007401, 51.0625920326483, 48.0636778973975, 48.2257813641678, 
112.661909405367, 110.35193500389, 48.7931434978639, 112.621383538674, 
75.1754827147322, 110.149305670427, 66.5839989759057, 54.6288683015952, 
56.4120064360686, 88.1842859230497, 105.731986200936, 108.771426202879, 
60.2214379051709, 59.1272395044713, 85.8337856548802, 119.429729143027, 
54.264135501362, 55.9662219024502, 57.9519893703866, 49.2389280314823, 
63.9498176408881, 125.589660880299, 123.036531278667, 62.7340416401108, 
60.7482741721744, 123.928100345904, 54.5883424349026)), row.names = c(NA, 
-48L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), groups = structure(list(
    Talker = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("T1", "T2", "T3", "T4"), class = "factor"), 
    Vowel = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L), .Label = c("i", "o", "u"), class = "factor"), .rows = list(
        c(7L, 8L, 9L, 12L), c(1L, 2L, 3L, 10L), c(4L, 5L, 6L, 
        11L), c(13L, 14L, 22L, 23L), c(15L, 18L, 19L, 20L), c(16L, 
        17L, 21L, 24L), c(25L, 27L, 32L, 33L), c(29L, 30L, 34L, 
        35L), c(26L, 28L, 31L, 36L), c(37L, 43L, 44L, 47L), c(38L, 
        39L, 41L, 48L), c(40L, 42L, 45L, 46L))), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

When I do this, three columns emerge in my new df "data", called "X.1" "X.2" and "X.3". Any insight into why this is happening is appreciated!

Comment: It would help others help you if you provided a [mcve]. In particular, you should [edit] your question to include the output of the R commands `dput(Tokens.Single)` and `dput(Tokens.Mixed)`. If those data frames are very large, you could do `dput(head(Tokens.Single, n))` for some `n`

Comment: When running `full_join(Tokens.Single, Tokens.Mixed)` on the data you provided, I do not get this behavior. Can you try the full join again in a **fresh** R session? If the problem does not occur after *only* assigning the data and running the `full_join()` line, then there is something else about your code that is causing the problem and you will again need to [edit] your question, this time to include the full minimum amount of your code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want better help you should creat a minimal reproducible example (reprex). But, this is a commom behaviour of the data.frame structure of R. The data.frame always put this X's, when a column name of yours, does not respect the rules of how you should name you variables in R. So problably a name in one of your tables, does not respect those rules. If you want to avoid this behaviour, you can transform both tables to Tibble's, with. Tibbles mantain the names of your columns, even if they dont respect those rules that I mention, but you will have to surround the column name with backsticks to refer to it:

```
library(tidyverse)

table1 <- as_tibble(table1)
table2 <- as_tibble(table2)

table1$`column name that dont respect rules`
```

But I think the better option will be to rename those column's that dont fit in those rules.